# Does Mahout support word stemming?

Tags: hadoop, mahout, stemming, porter-stemmer

I'm using mahout to do topic discovery using LDA. To prepare my data I use `seq2sparse` which tokenize the document and creates n-grams. However it does not support word stemming by default. I wonder to know is Mahout has any built-in word stemming? If not, should I implement my own? Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

You can precise your analyzer with the `seq2sparse` command :

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout seq2sparse
             ...
             --analyzerName (-a) analyzerName  The class name of the analyzer
```

The analyzer is an Apache Lucene analyzer, so you'll have to precise the name as followed, per example :

```
org.apache.lucene.analysis.fr.FrenchAnalyzer
```

I suggest that you read the [official documentation](https://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/creating-vectors-from-text.html) for more information about what you can do with the `seqsparse` command. You'll also need to read some Lucene [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/).

**PS:** You should use the same lucene version as in mahout.

Comment: Thanks, So I looked into Lucence and it looks like that there are different stemming algorithms, i.e. ``EnglishMinimalStemmer``, ``EnglishStemmer``. Do you know which one is better? The other question I have is how can I find out the version of my lucene version ?

Comment: The stemming algorithms should respond to your needs and use case. I can't say which is better. You have to evaluate both and see which one fits better to your model.

Comment: You can find Lucene's version in Mahout documentation or even for a closer look. You can't try the pom.xml in mahout source code.

Comment: I tried to pass a stemmer as the analyzer but it gives me an error message. IT looks like only the EnglsishAnalyzer class (or similar ones like FrenchAnalyze) can be used not a stemmer?

Comment: What version of mahout are you using?

Comment: The latest one which comes with Hortonworks 2.2 (mahout-examples-0.9.0.2.2.0.0-2041-job)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77122/discussion-between-h-z-and-eliasah).